# Code working fine as webservice get error in junit

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4

I had written one service as

```
@Service
public class ConverterService {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConverterService.class);

private static final String CONVERT_DTO_TO_ENTITY= "convertToEntity called with DTO: ";

@Autowired
private ModelMapper modelMapper;

/**
 * @param userActivityHistoryDto : user activity history object
 * @return - Returns UserActivityLog object
 * @throws JsonProcessingException - Exception raised
 */
public UserActivityLog convertToEntity(UserActivityHistoryDto userActivityHistoryDto) throws JsonProcessingException {
    LOGGER.debug(CONVERT_DTO_TO_ENTITY + userActivityHistoryDto);
    final UserActivityLog userActivityLog = modelMapper.map(userActivityHistoryDto, UserActivityLog.class); //getting null in junit
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ActivityDescriptionDto obj = userActivityHistoryDto.getActivityDescription();

    //Object to JSON in String
    String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    userActivityLog.setActivityDescription(jsonInString);
    return userActivityLog;
}
```

}

I am passing same object to webservice and test case but getting null junit and same object mapped perfectly in webservice call. Test case looks like

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ConverterServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
private ConverterService converterService;

@Mock
private ModelMapper modelMapper;

@Test
public void testConvertEntity() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    UserActivityHistoryDto userActivityHistoryDto = mapper.readValue(Resources.getResource("CreateUserHistoryLog.json"), UserActivityHistoryDto.class);

    UserActivityLog userActivityLog = converterService.convertToEntity(userActivityHistoryDto);
    Assert.assertEquals("UPD_COMPY",userActivityLog.getActivityTypeCode().getActivityTypeCode());
    Assert.assertEquals("CID",userActivityLog.getKeyId());
    Assert.assertEquals("202020",userActivityLog.getKeyValueText());
    Assert.assertEquals("I",userActivityLog.getAudienceTypeCode());
    Assert.assertNotNull(userActivityLog.getActivityDescription());
}
}
```

Please help me to know whats going wrong.

Comment: show us the stack trace. you have declared ModelMapper as a mock. Have you defined what should `modelMapper.map(...)` should return ?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a mock object, so you need stub the methods to say what you want to get when calling them. By default, unstubbed methods often return null.

As you are calling the method map for modelMapper, at your test you need something like:

```
when( modelMapper.map( anyObject( ), eq(UserActivityHistoryDto.class) ) ).thenReturn( /**What you want to return**/ new userActivityHistoryDto () );
```

Have a look to the documentation: [Mockito](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/Mockito.html)